# Loop/Search through an array till specific index

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search, fibonacci

How do you loop through an array until you you reach the last 50 elements of your array.I would  like to search the given array till I reach to the last 50 elements of this array, then the search is concluded with sequential look up of 50 elements. My question is that how can I construct such a loop and how to jump to the method that does the linear search.

Say I have the following Fibonacci search code. it similar to the binary search except that it uses the next Fibonacci number down to divided the list into two pars.

Fibonacci Search code:

```
public class Practice
{
static int Fib[] =
    {
        0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765,
        10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578,
        5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296,
    433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903
    };

static int binsrch_geq(int n, int val)
{
    int low, high, mid;
    int geq;
    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    geq = -1;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) >> 1;
        if (val < Fib[mid])
        {
            high = mid - 1;
            geq = mid;
        }
        else if (val > Fib[mid])
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return geq;
}

static int fibsrch(int arr[], int n, int val)
{
    int k, idx, offs;
    int prevn = -1, prevk = -1;
    if (n != prevn)
    {
        k = (n > 1) ? binsrch_geq(Fib.length, n) : 1;
        prevk = k;
        prevn = n;
    }
    else
    {
        k = prevk;
    }
    for (offs = 0; k > 0;)
    {
        idx = offs + Fib[--k];
        if (idx >= n || val < arr[idx])
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (val > arr[idx])
        {
            offs = idx;
            --k;
        }
        else
        {
            return idx;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int data[] =
    {
        1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 18, 20, 25, 27, 30, 32, 33, 36, 39, 41, 44, 47, 51, 53, 55, 60,61,64,66,69,71,72,
        74,75,79,80,81,83,87,88,90,92,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,105,106,109,111,112,119,120,122,124,126,129,130,134,
        135,138,139,143,144,145,146,149,150,153,159,160,164,166,167
    };
    int i, x, n;

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    x = 164;
    //////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////
    n = data.length;
    i = fibsrch(data, n, x);
    if (i >= 0)
    {
        System.out.println(x + " found at index " + (i+1));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(x + " was not found");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the array has at least 50 elements you can write:

```
public int searchInTop50(int[] arr, int val){
    for(int i = Math.max(0, arr.length - 50); i < arr.length; i++){
        if(a[i] == val)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It will return the index of the value if found, otherwise -1. It can be called like any other method. If I understand your question correctly, you can do a binary search on the first *n* - 50 elements and then if the value isn't found perform the `searchInTop50` method. to stop searching at a certain index, you can pass it to the binary search method's arguments. The start and stop indexes are usually passed to a recursive implementation of binary search. You may want to look into that.

Comment: for(int i = Math.max(0, arr.length - 50); i < arr.length; i++)